# Punctuation: I miss them too, they’re adorable. or (too; they’re adorable.) or (too. They’re adorable.)

Tags: punctuation

What is the right punctuation for the last sentence?

There were two parks in my old neighborhood, where kids used to ride their bicycles. I miss the park kids too; they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too; they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too, they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too. They’re adorable.​

Answer (score 0):

#1 and #3 are alright.  #2 has a comma splice problem.  We can fix that by adding the conjunction **for**:

> I miss the park kids too, **for** they’re adorable

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You can fix it better with:  «I **also** miss the park kids **as** they **were** adorable» No punctuation necessary

Comment: I'd be quite happy to use the comma splice here.  The second sentence is particularly short.  I know that if someone is going to be marking my punctuation I should use the semicolon. But the comma is simpler and less intrusive. So if I were writing for my own pleasure, I'd use splice.